# Strange Wordpress Duplicate Form Submission

Tags: wordpress, forms, submission

When submitting options on this page: https://www.easyrental.gr/me-endiaferei/?post_id=43907&cff_no_cache=dzlMZktMb3NyUXhtd3duUkp1Z1p6Zz09

I get a double form submission from some people.  It does not happen to everyone, probably 20% of submissions but it happens in Greece and other locations occaisionally.

The plugin is: Calculated Fields Form using wordpress.

Anyone may have an idea?

I am new to wordpress, Ive reached out to the developer and they said its not the plugin, possibly the server.